# Derivation of Post-Newtonian (PN) expression for acceleration in Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory, post-newtonian

The expression for the acceleration of a near-earth satellite as presented in the [IERS Technical note](http://www.iers.org/SharedDocs/Publikationen/EN/IERS/Publications/tn/TechnNote36/tn36.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1) is given by
\begin{equation} \label{eq:problemeq} \tag{1}
\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{GM_E}{c^2r^3} \left\{\left[2(\beta+\gamma)\frac{GM_E}{r} - \gamma \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}} \right] \mathbf{r} + 2(1+\gamma)(\mathbf{r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}})\dot{\mathbf{r}} \right\}.
\end{equation}

We are working in the Parametrised Post-Newtonian formalism, hence the dimensionless constants $\beta,\gamma$.

From what I can gather from [here](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series2/Descanso2_all.pdf) and [here](http://vixra.org/pdf/1303.0004v1.pdf) this expression can be derived from the "Schwarzschild isotropic one-body point mass metric".

Now, I know what the Schwarzschild metric looks like in isotropic coordinates but I can't see where Eq. (\ref{eq:problemeq}) comes from.

Another point to make is that in GR the dimensionless parameters $\beta,\gamma$ are equal to unity and when substituted above gives a well known formula for Schwarzschild precession which is given by
\begin{equation} \label{eq:problemeq2} \tag{1}
\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2} = \frac{GM_E}{c^2r^3} \left\{\left[4\frac{GM_E}{r} - \dot{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{r}} \right] \mathbf{r} + 4(\mathbf{r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}})\dot{\mathbf{r}} \right\}.
\end{equation}

Again, I don't recall this either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The derivation of that expression seems to be rather involved. I looked through the various references in IERS Technical Note No. 36 and AU Resolutions B1.3 and B1.4 (2000) and the best starting point I could find is [Klioner 2001; https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0107457] eq. (3) and the references for it [Will 1993] and [Klioner & Soffel 2000; https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9906123].

Comment: It's definitely quite involved. I don't expect it to be done in one sitting :) On the hunt for some resources that can be understood. I find the  old school PN guys quite difficult to follow!

Comment: The eq of motion for your case is $\frac{d^2x^\sigma}{ds^2} = \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{ds}\frac{dx^\nu}{ds} $ . Just plug in the Schwarzschild metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ into $ \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu\nu} = 1/2 g^{\sigma\alpha}( \frac{\partial g_{\mu\alpha}}{\partial x_\nu} + \frac{\partial g_{\nu\alpha}}{\partial x_\mu} -\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\alpha}) $ and do the math on the eq of motion. This is, i suppose, the simplest approach.

Comment: @MihaiB. Unfortunately this wouldn't work. That what you would do in a completely relativistic framework. However, this is expressed in terms of the PPN formalism.

Comment: That's very similar to the form used in Yeomans, D. K., et al. "Cometary orbit determination and nongravitational forces." Comets II (2004): 137-151, who reference Anderson J. D., et al. "Experimental test of general relativity using time-delay data from Mariner 6 and Mariner 7." Astrophys. J., 200, 221–233. The only difference is the use of the Gaussian gravitational constant $k$ instead of $GM_E$

Comment: Where in the [IERTS Technical Note](http://www.iers.org/SharedDocs/Publikationen/EN/IERS/Publications/tn/TechnNote36/tn36.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1) does your eqtn(1) appear?  Their eqtn (10.12) on p.155 looks similar but has additional terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are referencing my old paper. Well in my paper I was referencing to the other of your two references, the book by JPL. There is an expression numbered 4-26 on page 4-19 in that book that reduces to the expression you wrote above in the case of one static large mass and one small "test-body". The derivation of expression 4-26 is provided on page 4-22 to page 4-24 in the same book by the Jet Propulsion Laboratory. The derivation is a bit beyond me I must say but still.

https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series2/Descanso2_all.pdf

**Edit** I just wanted to add, in case someone arrives here looking for an expression, that the expression above only works well in the weak field limit. As is seen it approximates GR by introducing two velocity-dependent terms and one repulsive inverse cube term. This does not work well in the strong field regime. As the repulsive term gets stronger as you close in on the black hole, "bouncing" will occur. In the simulations below the green circle represents the Schwarzschild radius and the red circle the radius of the "innermost stable circular radius". As seen in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/469181/3pn-and-higher-order-post-newtonian-schwarzschild-approximation), the post-Newtonian expansion is available also at the 3PN level, including more terms. Maybe that expression will work better in stronger fields.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the response and information. I figured it out quite some time ago ;)