# Can the Schwarzschild orbit equation be solved exactly?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, orbital-motion, geodesics

The Schwarzschild orbit is
$U'' + U = 1 + \varepsilon \cdot U^2$.
I've only seen turning-point analysis that demonstrates shift of perihelion.
Is there an exact solution?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? While you've made the physics context clear, the question is clearly about analytic solutions to a particular differential equation.

Comment: If there is a closed, exact solution, that is a complex number and no real solution is possible, this indicates GR is NOT!! The correct representation of gravitational interactions.. OK,, I'm fishing bc there is such a solution... perhaps a better way to ask, but it is a critical issue for GR.

Comment: I'm about 70% sure that I found an exact solution on this site recently, albeit one involving some obscure special function (so it wasn't terribly illuminating). I'll see if I can dig it up but no promises.

Comment: Michael: thanks... it's an old and important issue for GR... in which I do not believe. My solution is in complex exponentials or sines and cosines. Pretty straightforward... 

Comment: You need elliptic integrals / functions. I realise that you're asking about "closed" orbits, but for "hyperbolic" trajectories, rob has a great analysis for a massive particle here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/774043/123208 I have some info for photon trajectories here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/766180/123208

Comment: Since you apparently have (or think you know) an answer to this question, you should post an answer.

Comment: What kind of exakt solution are you looking for? You want to find the acceleration as a function of position and velocity? If so this basically the same question as this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784415/

Comment: Did you even check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Exact_solution_using_elliptic_functions) ? Before saying you are sure you solved the equation, test it against the others' solution.

Comment: I solved the DE... what does Wikipedia have to do with it   But..

Comment: Yes my advisors and I have peer reviewed this solution... they do not know of an exact solution..

Comment: Except the Phi(r) integral, which one comment addressed the use of elliptical integrals. Trust me, there is an exact solution  

Answer (score 7):

Closed-form analytic solutions for bound timelike geodesics around a Schwarzschild black hole were first (to the best of my knowledge) given by [Charles G. Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Galton_Darwin) (grandson of) in 1959 in this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1959.0015) (unfortunately paywalled).

In terms of $u =1/r$, and making use of the fact that energy $E$ and angular momentum $L$ are constants of motion, the Schwarzchild geodesic equation can be written in first order form:

\begin{align}
\left( \frac{du}{d\phi}\right)^2 &= 2M u^3 -u^2 + \frac{2M}{L}u + \frac{E^2-1}{L^2}\\
&=2M (u-u_1)(u-u_2)(u-u_3),
\end{align}

where $M$ is the mass of the Schwarzschild solution (also units such that $G=c=1$).

For bound orbits, $0<u_1\leq u_2\leq u_3$, and the solution
is given by

$$ u= u_1 + (u_2-u_3) sn^2(\xi(\phi),k),$$

where $sn$ is the [Jacobi elliptic sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions), elliptic parameter $k= (u_2-u_1)/(u_3-u_1)$, and

$$\xi(\phi) = \sqrt{\frac{M(u_3-u_1)}{2}}\phi + \xi_0.$$

Comment: You can also examine the Schwarzschild solution in Mino time as presented here in equations (32)-(53), if you set spin to zero: "Analytic solutions for the motion of spinning particles near spherically symmetric black holes and exotic compact objects", https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.00021

Comment: @Void For Schwarzschild geodesics $\phi = L \lambda+ \lambda_0$. So Mino time and $\phi$ are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Sure, just an alternative unpaywalled source.

Answer (score -4):

Exact solutions for this equation are generally not available, and the orbits near a Schwarzschild black hole usually rely on numerical methods and perturbation theory.

Comment: It is a fact that I solved the orbit, though it turns out to be a complex number and by the same method, show no real solution is possible. Paper available by email .