# Order of magnitude of time derivatives of gravitational potential and gravitational vector potential on Earth

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, order-of-magnitude, post-newtonian

*[This question is connected with [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/796750/132418). Since the estimation and measurement of spatial gradients and time derivatives have very different levels of difficulties, I thought it best to ask two separate questions]*

In post-Newtonian approximation of gravitation, the metric on and around the Earth is taken to have the expression
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1+\frac{2}{c^2}U+ \frac{2}{c^4}(\psi-U^2) + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& -\frac{4}{c^3} V_x + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& -\frac{4}{c^3} V_y + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& -\frac{4}{c^3} V_z + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
\\\\
-\frac{4}{c^3} V_x + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& 1+ \frac{2}{c^2} U + \mathrm{O}(c^{-4}) & 0 & 0
\\\\
-\frac{4}{c^3} V_y + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& 0 & 1+ \frac{2}{c^2} U + \mathrm{O}(c^{-4}) & 0
\\\\
-\frac{4}{c^3} V_z + \mathrm{O}(c^{-5})
& 0 & 0 & 1+ \frac{2}{c^2} U + \mathrm{O}(c^{-4})
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in a coordinate system $(ct, x, y,z)$, where $U$, $\psi$, $V_i$ depend on all coordinates, including time. $U$ is related to the Newtonian gravitational potential, and $(V_j)$ is the so-called gravitational vector potential. See eg Poisson & Will 2014, eqns (8.2). This metric is used for example for GPS purposes, see eg Petit & Luzum 2010.

These potentials on Earth have a time dependence both because Earth is non-static and because of the movement of massive bodies in the Solar System.

**Can anyone provide an order of magnitude for the time derivative of the gravitational potential and the vector potential**:
$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} \approx \mathord{?}\ \mathrm{m^2/s^3}
\qquad
\frac{\partial V_j}{\partial t} \approx \mathord{?}\ \mathrm{m^3/s^4}
$$
I've been looking in the references above, in the references given in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313146/132418) and its answer, but I don't manage to find it. [This article](https://doi.org/10.1029/2021JB022392) has potentially useful information, but I didn't manage to extract estimates from it. Cheers!

**References**:

- Poisson, Will: [*Gravity: Newtonian, Post-Newtonian, Relativistic*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139507486) (CUP 2014)
- Petit, Luzum: [*IERS Conventions*](http://www.iers.org/TN36/), International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service, Technical Note 36.